# How to word-wrap using specific delimiters, without dynamic allocation

Tags: c, string, word-wrap

I have a program that displays UTF-8 encoded strings with a size limitation (say `MAX_LEN`).
Whenever I get a string with a length > `MAX_LEN`, I want to find out where I could split it so it would be printed gracefully.

For example:

```
#define MAX_LEN 30U
const char big_str[] = "This string cannot be displayed on one single line: it must be splitted"
```

Without process, the output will looks like:

```
"This string cannot be displaye" // Truncated because of size limitation
"d on one single line: it must "
"be splitted"
```

The client would be able to chose eligible delimiters for the split but for now, I defined a list of delimiters by default:

```
#define DEFAULT_DELIMITERS " ;:,)]" // Delimiters to track in the string
```

So I am looking for an elegant and lightweight way of handling these issue **without using `malloc`**: my API should **not** return the sub-strings, I just want the positions of the sub-strings to display.

I already have some ideas that I will propose in answer: any feedback (e.g. pros and cons) would be appreciated, but most of all I am interested in alternatives solutions.

Comment: You might like to have a look at `strpbrk()`.

Comment: I just read the man page: thanks, it will be useful indeed for the implementation of the API itself !

Comment: You want the api or how to use it?

Comment: What do you need the substrings (or "views" into the whole strings) for? Why not write a function `print_wrapped` that does both the splitting and the printing?

Comment: @valter I actually want a "design", I can take care of the details within the implementation

Comment: @MOehm I have an API that is responsible of the display in my application, this is where the size limitation comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want the positions of the sub-strings to display.

So all you need is one function analysing your input returning the positions where a delimiter was found.

A possible appoach using [`strpbrk()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strpbrk.3.html) assuming C99 at least:

```
#include <unistd.h> /* for ssize_t */
#include <string.h>

#define DELIMITERS (" ;.")

void find_delimiter_positions(
  const char * input,
  const char * delimiters,
  ssize_t * delimiter_positions)
{
  ssize_t dp_current = 0;
  const char * p = input;
  while (NULL != (p = strpbrk(p, delimiters)))
  {
    delimiter_positions[dp_current] = p - input;
    ++dp_current;
    ++p;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char input[] = "some randrom data; more.";
  size_t input_length = strlen(input);
  ssize_t delimiter_positions[input_length];
  for (size_t s = 0; s < input_length; ++s)
  {
    delimiter_positions[s] = -1;
  }

  find_delimiter_positions(input, DELIMITERS, delimiter_positions);

  for (size_t s = 0; -1 != delimiter_positions[s]; ++s)
  {
    /* print out positions */
  }
}
```

For why C99: C99 introduces V(ariable) L(ength) A(rray), which are necessary here to get around the limitation to not use dynamic memory allocation.

If VLAs also may not be used one needs to fall back a defining a maximum number of possible occurences of delimiters per string. The latter however might be feasable as the maximum length of the string to be parsed is given, which in turn would imply the maximum number of possible delimiters per string.

For the latter case those lines from the example above

```
  char input[] = "some randrom data; more.";
  size_t input_length = strlen(input);
  ssize_t delimiter_positions[input_length];
```

could be replaced by

```
  char input[MAX_INPUT_LEN] = "some randrom data; more.";
  size_t input_length = strlen(input);
  ssize_t delimiter_positions[MAX_INPUT_LEN];
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach that doesn't require additional storage is to make the wrapping function call a callback function for each substring. In the example below, the string is just printed with plain old `printf`, but the callback could call any other API function.

Things to note:

- There is a function `next` that should advance a pointer to the next UTF-8 character. The encoding width for an UTF-8 char can be seen from its first byte.
- The space and punctuation delimiters are treated slightly differently: Spaces are neither appended to the end or beginning of a line. (If there aren't any consecutive spaces in the text, that is.) Punctuation is retained at the end of a line.

Here's an example implementation:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DELIMITERS " ;:,)]"

/*
 *      Advance to next character. This should advance the pointer to
 *      up to three chars, depending on the UTF-8 encoding. (But at the
 *      moment, it doesn't.)
 */
static const char *next(const char *p)
{
    return p + 1;
}

typedef struct {
    const char *begin;
    const char *end;
} substr_t;

/*
 *      Wraps the text and stores the found substring' ranges into
 *      the lines struct. Return the number of word-wrapped lines.
 */
int wrap(const char *text, int width, substr_t *lines, uint32_t max_num_lines)
{
    const char *begin = text;
    const char *split = NULL;
    uint32_t num_lines = 1;
    int l = 0;

    while (*text) {
        if (strchr(DELIMITERS, *text)) {
            split = text;
            if (*text != ' ') split++;
        }

        if (l++ == width) {
            if (split == NULL) split = text;
            lines[num_lines - 1].begin = begin;
            lines[num_lines - 1].end = split;
            //write(fileno(stdout), begin, split - begin);

            text = begin = split;
            while (*begin == ' ') begin++;
            split = NULL;
            l = 0;
            num_lines++;

            if (num_lines > max_num_lines) {
                //abort();
                return -1;
            }
        }

        text = next(text);
    }

    lines[num_lines - 1].begin = begin;
    lines[num_lines - 1].end = text;
    //write(fileno(stdout), begin, split - begin);

    return num_lines;
}

int main()
{
    const char *text = "I have a program that displays UTF-8 encoded strings "
        "with a size limitation (say MAX_LEN). Whenever I get a string with a "
        "length > MAX_LEN, I want to find out where I could split it so it "
        "would be printed gracefully.";

    substr_t lines[100];
    const uint32_t max_num_lines = sizeof(lines) / sizeof(lines[0]);

    const int num_lines = wrap(text, 48, lines, max_num_lines);
    if (num_lines < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: can't split into %d lines\n", max_num_lines);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //printf("num_lines = %d\n", num_lines);
    for (int i=0; i < num_lines; i++) {
        FILE *stream = stdout;
        const ptrdiff_t line_length = lines[i].end - lines[i].begin;
        write(fileno(stream), lines[i].begin, line_length);
        fputc('\n', stream);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Addendum**: Here's another approach that builds loosely on the `strtok` pattern, but without modifying the string. It requires a state and that state must be initialised with the string to print and the maximum line width:

```
struct wrap_t {
    const char *src;
    int width;
    int length;
    const char *line;
};

int wrap(struct wrap_t *line)
{
    const char *begin = line->src;
    const char *split = NULL;
    int l = 0;

    if (begin == NULL) return -1;
    while (*begin == ' ') begin++;
    if (*begin == '\0') return -1;

    while (*line->src) {
        if (strchr(DELIMITERS, *line->src)) {
            split = line->src;
            if (*line->src != ' ') split++;
        }

        if (l++ == line->width) {
            if (split == NULL) split = line->src;

            line->line = begin;
            line->length = split - begin;
            line->src = split;

            return 0;
        }

        line->src = next(line->src);
    }

    line->line = begin;
    line->length = line->src - begin;

    return 0;
}
```

All definitions not shown (`DELIMITERS`, `next`) are as above and the basic algorithm hasn't changed. I think this method is easy to use for the client:

```
int main()
{
    const char *text = "I have a program that displays UTF-8 encoded strings "
        "with a size limitation (say MAX_LEN). Whenever I get a string with a "
        "length > MAX_LEN, I want to find out where I could split it so it "
        "would be printed gracefully.";

    struct wrap_t line = {text, 60};

    while (wrap(&line) == 0) {
        printf("%.*s\n", line.length, line.line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should have precised that I work in an big multi-threaded environment where Callbacks are prohibited as it is painful to debug... There are some interesting ideas in your post though, thanks.

Comment: @M Oehm: I hope you don't mind my edit, otherwise, please, rollback. @Coconop: check the update. Does it help?

Comment: I'll need a deeper look but it seems better indeed. BTW @jweyrich thanks for the title edit and the tag :)

Comment: @jweyrich: Apparently the OP asks for an API design. My idea was to use callbacks, but that didn't suit the OP's requirements. (I'm not buying his argument about callbacks, btw.) Your design is good, but not very different from Coconop's own solution #2, in which he doesn't like the fixed max. array size.

Comment: @Coconop: you're welcome. I'd suggest using dynamic programming to solve the word-wrapping, but @M Oehm's solution seems quite satisfactory for any width > 10.

Comment: @M Oehm: indeed, it's pretty much the same. Well, if he can't (or doesn't want to) use callbacks, the best one could do is make the function work like an iterator. Maybe something like `for (char *text = anything; text != NULL; next_line(text, width, ...) { ... }`.

Comment: @jweyrich: I've come up with something else and added it, but I've left your edits as they were.

Comment: @MOehm remembers me of **[std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)**. Nice one! :-) Pity I can't upvote twice.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution1

A function that will be called successively until the whole string is processed: it would return the count of bytes to recopy to create the sub-strings:

The API:

```
/** 
 * Return the length between the beginning of the string and the 
 * last delimiter (such that returned length <= max_length)
 */
size_t get_next_substring_length(
    const char * str,    // The string to be splitted
    const char * delim,  // String of eligible delimiters for a split
    size_t max_length);  // The maximum length of resulting substring
```

On the client' side:

```
size_t shift = 0;
for(;;)
{
    // Where do we start within big_str ?
    const char * tmp = big_str + shift;

    size_t count = get_next_substring_length(tmp, DEFAULT_DELIMITERS, MAX_LEN);
    if(count)
    {
        // Allocate a sub-string and recopy "count" bytes
        // Display the sub-string
        shift += count;
    }
    else // End Of String (or error)
    {
        // Handle potential error
        // Exit the loop
    }
}
```

## Solution2

Define a custom structure to store positions and lengths of sub-strings:

```
const char * str = "This is a long test string";
struct substrings 
{
    const char * str; // Beginning of the substring
    size_t length;    // Length of the substring
} sub[] = { {&str[0], 4}, 
              {&str[5], 2}, 
              {&str[8], 1},
              {&str[10], 4},
              {&str[15], 4},
              {&str[20], 6},
              {NULL, 0} };
```

The API:

```
size_t find_substrings(
    struct substrings ** substr, 
    size_t max_length, 
    const char * delimiters, 
    const char * str);
```

On the client' side:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH 20U
struct substrings substr[ARRAY_LENGTH];

// Fill the structure
find_substrings(
    &substr, 
    ARRAY_LENGTH, 
    DEFAULT_DELIMITERS, 
    big_str);

// Browse the structure
for (struct substrings * sub = &substr[0]; substr->str; sub++) 
{
    // Display sub->length bytes of sub->str
}
```

Some things are bothering me though:

- in **Solution1** I don't like the infinite loop, it is often bug prone
- in **Solution2** I fixed `ARRAY_LENGTH` arbitrarily but it should vary depending of input string length

Comment: Strings are finite! What is the test to break out of the loop? What prevents it from being performed in the `for`? Maybe a `do` ... `while` loop could be better?

Comment: To me it looks your 2nd proposals implements more then specfiid in you question, as it does seem to return the sub-strings.

Comment: @alk It just fills a pre-allocated structure with the addresses of the found sub-strings and their respective lengths.

Comment: Why? Having the delimiters' positions allows you to directly access the sub-strings by using the positions as index to the input.

Comment: Yes but I want a little more intelligence in the function: it should not store any delimiters position, otherwise I'll end up with very short sub-strings like `"this ", "is ", "a ", "string "`. I want the sub-strings to have a length as close as possible to my defined `MAX_LENGTH`

Comment: I'd seperate parsing the current format from applying any new format.